Signers from extension-dapp and ui-keyring expect different data types?
Can both @polkadot/extension-dapp and @polkadot/ui-keyring work together on the frontend somehow? I am helping develop a dapp that needs to sign an external message composed of bytes, but signer.signRaw() from extension-dapp only takes a hex-encoded string for the data param. The message needing to be sent requires the data to be of type u8IntArray because it uses this unique signature to verify some process down the line.
Keyring/ui-keyring is able to access the .sign() method, which does take custom types and a byte array value directly, but because we are building an open-source dapp it seems weird to ask a user for their secret phrase/mnemonic or raw mini secret just to sign a message (not to be confused with a Polkadot extrinsic; my issue isn't there), but currently .sign() is the only thing that accepts byte data, as we have demonstrated this in our POC.

You could convert the bytes to hex using u8aToHex from @polkadot/util, sign with signer.signRaw() and then reconvert to bytes with hexToU8a
